# Arquillian fails since it cannot undeploy test war after running the test case

Tags: tomcat7, jboss-arquillian

I am running arquillian test cases on managed tomcat .
 When  I am running a sample test case , all of the tests in the test case passes but the whole test  fails since arquillian cannot undeploy the test war after testing process. Here is the failure message

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: The server command (/text/undeploy?path=%2FArquillianTest) failed with content (FAIL - Unable to delete [C:\WebServers\ArquillianTest\apache-tomcat-7.0.29\webapps\ArquillianTest]. The continued presence of this file may cause problems.).
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.tomcat.CommonTomcatManager.processResponse(CommonTomcatManager.java:274)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.tomcat.CommonTomcatManager.execute(CommonTomcatManager.java:227)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.tomcat.CommonTomcatManager.undeploy(CommonTomcatManager.java:112)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.tomcat.managed_7.TomcatManagedContainer.undeploy(TomcatManagedContainer.java:221)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$4.call(ContainerDeployController.java:205)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$4.call(ContainerDeployController.java:185)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.executeOperation(ContainerDeployController.java:271)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.undeploy(ContainerDeployController.java:184)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createDeploymentContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:78)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createContainerContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$2.perform(ContainerDeployController.java:119)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$2.perform(ContainerDeployController.java:110)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.forEachDeployment(ContainerDeployController.java:263)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.forEachDeployedDeployment(ContainerDeployController.java:249)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.undeployManaged(ContainerDeployController.java:109)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.execute(ContainerEventController.java:108)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:75)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.afterClass(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:87)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3$1.evaluate(Arquillian.java:204)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:314)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$100(Arquillian.java:46)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:199)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:147)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

How should I solve this problem, it seems that it is not happening always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Undeployment problem solved by modifying context.xml from /tomcat/conf folder in this way

```
<Context antiJarLocking="true" antiResourceLocking="true">
```

[here is the post with more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873219/cannot-undeploy-a-web-app-completely-in-tomcat-7)